# What is the best way to animate many images?

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation

I can not animate many images with animationImages and startAnimating as it uses too much memory and crashes. What is the best way to animate 100 images in a portion of my iPhone screen (not full screen)? Is there an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two solutions :

1°) Subclass UIView and in the drawRect you draw each time another image. You add a NSTimer to create the animation ^^

2°) Do the same as 1°) but with OpenGL ^^

Good Luck ! :-)

Comment: By the way, maybe you could begin be setting answer of your questions as finished before asking another question ^^

Comment: How do I set answers as finished?

Comment: On the page of your question, you have a mark below the 0 || -1 || 1 || ... number (on the left). Click it when the answer is the best.

Comment: Do you know where I can find an example of how to display images with OpenGL?

Comment: You have an OpenGL ES example if you create an empty project with xCode ^^ then check google to draw an image